# Error while installing phpmyadmin package in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

```
root@anonymous-20-a213l:~# apt-get -y install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is the error I have got after doing "sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin" and before doing this process I have already updated by "sudo apt-get update". Please help me .
Thanks

Comment: what is the output of `apt-cache policy php5-mcrypt`

Comment: php5-mcrypt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.3.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.3.5-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages

Comment: what is the output of `apt-cache policy php5`?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 0):

*Because you don't give us anymore information …*

All packages are in the Precise repositories:

- [php5gd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise-updates&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5-gd)
- [php5-mcrypt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5-mcrypt)

You could install the packages separately:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and maybe (because recommended)

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```